# How do I bring back my imports/interfaces and fix my projects?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was working on my java final project last night, it was working fine, but then I continued today and I have sooooooo many errors, all my imports aren't working, and neither is my interfaces. I didn't change any settings, the only thing I did do was I updated intelij to the newest update, but I did that before I worked on my project yesterday. Also, all my past projects and projects I make now are broken in the same way. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Updates sometimes mess up config files. 
I had this problem on IntelliJ 2020.1 and to fix I did:
 1. Go to the top navbar and click `File`
 2. `Invalidate Caches and Restart` > `Invalidate and Restart`

If the project continues strange, you can also try the following:
 1. Go to the top navbar and click `File`
 2. `Close project`
 3. Click on the `x` to delete the project
 4. Using your file system, delete the `.idea` folder
 5. Try to open your project again, using `Open or Import`

Comment: That fixed some of it, but my javafx imports are still not working, also the file structure/file explorer window is gone.

Comment: See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx. Make sure you have all the [dependencies configured](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

Comment: Verify if your dependecies manager is working propertly @Tnings. Maven ou Gradle sometimes are hard to use, but try to make a 'clean start', by removing downloaded dependencies and installing it all again from scratch.